# Creating a next button to set focus in next edittext

Tags: android

I am new at Android development, I do not know much about Android development. My application requirement is that  I am using a linear layout for arranging the components. There are five text viewm five edittext and two buttons. First is for submitting and the second one is the "next". I have almost completed the app, but I want to add some extra functionality in my app, that's why I added the "next" button.

When the user presses the next button, I want the focus to move to the next editText. When we reach the last edit text, and the user presses next again, then the focus should go back to the first editText.

Please help me,
thanks in advance.

This is the main activity:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private   Button  next_button = null;


@Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(view==next_button)
        {
            event.dispatch(callback);
        }
    }

KeyEvent.Callback callback = new Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int count, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        youredittext.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a new developer, then there is an advice for you to the future. When you work with some program components from Android API, look through the references of specific classes, searching an API which may satisfy your needs.

As an example, all visual components in Android are represented as instances of `View` class. So the best way to find out some API you need is to look through the thorough documentation of this class ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)).

Also [there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) is a good guide about how to works with views which describes how to interact with [focus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#HandlingFocus)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:nextFocusDown="@id/nextedittext"` to your EditTexts, so when you hit enter focus is sent to the next EditText